# Data Validation in Google Sheets Using Multiple Criteria

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, regex, google-sheets-data-validation

I have a column with text in the format:

```
[text:more text/numbers]
```

I want to ensure whatever is entered into the cell conforms to this syntax, or at least as much of it as possible.
`text` is always 5 characters long and capitalized. The part after the colon is of variable length.

Currently, I am using simple data validation to check that the trailing `]` is in the cell. The criteria are `Text contains ]`, rejecting input for everything without the `]`.

Using an IF statement, could I check the cell for those symbols/string lengths and reject everything that doesn't conform? Ideally, I would use the formula within the data validation feature, rather than as a script, for example:

Criteria: `Custom formula is =(FORMULA HERE)`

Any ideas would be appreciated on this.

Answer (score 1):

Use [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Regular_expression) and [REGEXMATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292?hl=en)

I think that `=REGEXMATCH(A1,"^\[.*]$")` should work.

Answer (score 0):

- taking it on next level it would be:

  ```
  =REGEXMATCH(A2, "^\[.{5}:.*/\d+]$")
  ```

  [image: 1]

  ...where requirements for **`TRUE`** outcome are:

  - starting with **`[`**
  - 5 characters before **`:`**
  - any length characters between **`:`** and **`/`**
  - numbers after **`/`**
  - ending with **`]`**